# org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type Bean with qualifiers @Default

Tags: maven, jsf, dependencies, cdi, omnifaces

My project was working fine yesterday. The only thing I did was to change the structure from a single war to a multi module pom. If I understand correctly the stacktrace there is ambiguousity between weld and omnifaces websocket lib. However there doesn't seem to be any call to any of my methods on the stacktrace. So maybe it's a problem with omnifaces ? I don't even use omnifaces websockets, I use javax.websocket. I did however try it out in this project in the past, and I did a search on "org.omnifaces.cdi" and commented out things from sub packages like `@Param` but the problem remains.
Also I don't understand why the ambiguousity seem to be from the 2 exact same classes:

> - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
> - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

```
[2016-06-25 03:13:59,430] Artifact core:war: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 4 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type SocketSessionManager with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketPushContextProducer.socketSessions
  at org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketPushContextProducer.socketSessions(SocketPushContextProducer.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:367)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type SocketSessionManager with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketChannelManager.socketSessions
  at org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketChannelManager.socketSessions(SocketChannelManager.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:367)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type SocketUserManager with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager.socketUsers
  at org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager.socketUsers(SocketSessionManager.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketUserManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketUserManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:367)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001318: Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between: 
  - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.resolve(BeanManagerImpl.java:1235)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validatePseudoScopedInjectionPoint(Validator.java:926)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.reallyValidatePseudoScopedBean(Validator.java:902)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.reallyValidatePseudoScopedBean(Validator.java:917)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validatePseudoScopedBean(Validator.java:879)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:138)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
"}}
```

Comment: Your runtime classpath is polluted with multiple OmniFaces libraries. Cleanup it, also in the server side if necessary. Just to be sure, OmniFaces is designed as a WAR library and therefore WAR/WEB-INF/lib is the only right place and it should absolutely not reside elsewhere (e.g. EAR/lib or Server/lib), see also installation instructions at its homepage.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, I knew having the jar instead of the maven dependency would come back to bite me :). Seems like you included the fix in the RC2 which is in maven so I don't need to worry about this anymore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type SocketSessionManager with qualifiers @Default
>     at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketPushContextProducer.socketSessions

Basically, Weld discovered multiple CDI managed beans which could be injected in `private SocketSessionManager socketSessions` field of the [`SocketPushContextProducer`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/cdi/push/SocketPushContextProducer.java) class. They are listed thereafter:

> Possible dependencies:
>
> - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
> - Managed Bean [class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketSessionManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

In this specific case they are however exactly the same. This means that there are multiple `SocketSessionManager` classes in the runtime classpath. This in turn means that there are multiple OmniFaces libraries/dependencies present in the runtime classpath (or a dirty build/(hot)deploy which could be solved by trashing server's work/temp folders or spawning a clean server instance).

You need to make sure that there's only one OmniFaces library in the runtime classpath and that it ends up in WAR's `/WEB-INF/lib`.

This is not specifically related to websockets. It just happened to be the first OmniFaces-related class which is scanned by Weld. It could occur on any other CDI managed bean bundled in OmniFaces.

Comment: i am having a similar issue but, couldn't find the root cause. Could you pls help ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537209/weld-001409-ambiguous-dependencies-for-type-stepcontext-with-qualifiers-defaul

Comment: @BalusC I am facing similar issue. Could u please help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938597/weld-001409-ambiguous-dependencies-for-type-injectionpoint-with-qualifiers

Comment: @BalusC Cleaned and all is working fine: OmniFaces 3.4.1, Weld 3.1.3.Final & CDI 2.0, JBoss WildFly 18.0.1.Final, Undertow 2.0.27.Final, Mojarra 2.3.9.SP04, Faces 2.3, & PrimeFace 7.0.12.

Answer (score 6):

It could also be just a version change in pom, and maven build cache inconsistency.
A 
     `mvn clean`
helped in my case.

Comment: ha yeah. good one thanks for posting this for those of us googling this error.

Comment: It worked!! Tks