# WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type StepContext with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, cdi, weld, jsr352, jberet

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/kaape/jberet-standalone-example) example in java SE mode from my windows command prompt. I have built a jar with all dependencies included in it and running it from my command prompt.

but, keep getting [this](https://github.com/kaape/jberet-standalone-example/issues/3) error. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38031546/1538815), i understand that there could be multiple StepContext classes in my runtime classpath.

i now replaced the maven-assembly plugin with the maven-shade plugin to build my fat jar and i can see the following warning while packaging the jar

```
[WARNING] javax.inject-1.jar, weld-se-2.2.15.Final.jar define 6 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING] - javax.inject.Inject 
[WARNING] - javax.inject.Singleton 
[WARNING] - javax.inject.Scope 
[WARNING] - javax.inject.Named 
[WARNING] - javax.inject.Provider 
[WARNING] - javax.inject.Qualifier
```

I updated the following dependency to provided and now i don't see the above said warning while packaging but, am still getting exceptions when running the newly generated jar

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Current exception while executing the JAR file

```
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type InjectionPoint with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @BatchProperty public org.jberet.creation.BatchBeanProducer.getStringList(InjectionPoint)
  at org.jberet.creation.BatchBeanProducer.getStringList(BatchBeanProducer.java:0)
  Possible dependencies:
  - Implicit Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl$InstanceInjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.jboss.weld.injection.EmptyInjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:392)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:294)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:135)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:168)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:543)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type InjectionPoint with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @BatchProperty public org.jberet.creation.BatchBeanProducer.getStringBuilder(InjectionPoint)
  at org.jberet.creation.BatchBeanProducer.getStringBuilder(BatchBeanProducer.java:0)
  Possible dependencies:
  - Implicit Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl$InstanceInjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.jboss.weld.injection.EmptyInjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:392)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:294)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:135)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:168)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:543)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator.validateBeans(ConcurrentValidator.java:76)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:504)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:435)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:148)
        at org.jberet.se.SEArtifactFactory.<init>(SEArtifactFactory.java:29)
        at org.jberet.se.BatchSEEnvironment.getArtifactFactory(BatchSEEnvironment.java:133)
        at org.jberet.operations.JobOperatorImpl.<init>(JobOperatorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
```

***How can i resolve this problem ?***

Comment: When using Maven Shade plugin to build my fat JAR shows following output [WARNING] javax.inject-1.jar, weld-se-2.2.15.Final.jar define 6 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - javax.inject.Inject
[WARNING]   - javax.inject.Singleton
[WARNING]   - javax.inject.Scope
[WARNING]   - javax.inject.Named
[WARNING]   - javax.inject.Provider
[WARNING]   - javax.inject.Qualifier

Comment: The unusual part is that Weld is complaining about ambiguous dependency for a javax.inject SPI class `InjectionPoint`.  Usually we see this type of errors for some application bean classes, which should be easier to debug since it's your own class.  Both classes (`EmptyInjectionPoint` and `org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.InstanceInjectionPoint` implement `InjectionPoint`, hence the ambiguity.  But I'm not sure why Weld is confused with its own classes.  I guess some Weld-related configuration is lost/overwritten during the fat jar generation process.

Comment: I suggest you follow up with Weld and CDI experts.  Or if you think the problem is on JBeret side, please file a JBeret issue with a reproducible test app.

Comment: @cheng the only configuration files i have are jberet.properties and batch (JSL) XML

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your flattening causes the weld implementation to end up in a jar w/ a beans.xml that causes unintentional parts of the library to show up as managed beans due to a bean discovery mode of "all" (which is also the case of an empty beans.xml with no version).

You should minimally make sure it's bean-discovery-mode="annotated" if you're going to stuff the weld impl into one big jar w/ your application.

Comment: ok, let me trying adding a beans.xml with bean-discovery-mode="annotated" and try running the app

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to run a executable (fat) JAR of a Java batch program in Java SE mode using JBERET implementation.

[This link](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/camel-cdi-projects-as-fat-jar-td5786762.html) mentioned that and once i switched to 2.4.5.Final it worked fine.

> Until recently nested / fat JAR wasn’t working with Weld until it’s been fixed in Weld 2.3.4 with WELD-1930