# WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type InjectionPoint with qualifiers

Tags: jboss, cdi, weld, jboss-weld, microprofile

I am doing POC on CDI2.0 with JavaSE using wildfly Weld for CDI implementation.I am able to run the application using maven exec:java command. I have added maven single jar with dependency plugin to make a single jar with java main class. took single jar and executes the jar also working good ( java -jar appl*.jar).

I have added FaultTolerence ( Microprofile ) using SmallRye. it is also working good using maven exec:java command. But not working in Jar with dependency getting below mentioned error. Though  I have added `<exclude name="org.jboss.weld.**" />` in beans.xml

how to resolve this problem ?

I want a jar which has  all dependency and run without any issue

project is available in my git repo **https://github.com/Gnanapandithan/standalone**

I have followed http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/cdi/building-a-cdi-2-standalone-java-application this and added Faulttolerence ( SmallRye), but not working.

```
@Asynchronous
    @Retry(maxRetries = 2,retryOn = NullPointerException.class, delay = 200)
    @Fallback(fallbackMethod = "sayHello")
    public Future<String> greet() {
        try {
            System.out.println(" Greet ..................");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String s = null;
        s.length();
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("OK");
    }

    private Future<String> sayHello() {
        System.out.println(" sayHello...");
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture( "I am from Hello..");
    }
```

**pom.XML**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.SP1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.fault-tolerance</groupId>
        <artifactId>microprofile-fault-tolerance-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.config</groupId>
        <artifactId>microprofile-config-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
        <artifactId>smallrye-fault-tolerance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
        <artifactId>smallrye-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13-beta-1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.demo.small.AppMain</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.demo.small.AppMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

**Exception:**

```
INFO: WELD-001125: Illegal bean type rx.functions.Func1<java.util.List<? extends rx.Observable<?>>, rx.Observable<?>[]> ignored on [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] final static  class rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ToArrayFunc1
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 10 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type InjectionPoint with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer.getConfig(InjectionPoint)
  at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer.getConfig(ConfigProducer.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Implicit Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Default],
  - Managed Bean [class io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigInjectionBean$InjectionPointMetadataInjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:386)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:526)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.CommonForkJoinPoolExecutorServices.lambda$wrap$0(CommonForkJoinPoolExecutorServices.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:391)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.quietlyJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:1079)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.invokeAll(ForkJoinPool.java:2725)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator.validateBeans(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:487)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:490)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:804)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:176)
    at com.demo.small.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:12)
Exception 1 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type InjectionPoint with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Dependent @Produces @ConfigProperty io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer.produceDoubleConfigProperty(InjectionPoint)
  at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer.produceDoubleConfigProperty(ConfigProducer.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Implicit Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Default],
  - Managed Bean [class io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigInjectionBean$InjectionPointMetadataInjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:386)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:526)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.CommonForkJoinPoolExecutorServices.lambda$wrap$0(CommonForkJoinPoolExecutorServices.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:391)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.quietlyJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:1079)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.invokeAll(ForkJoinPool.java:2725)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator.validateBeans(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:487)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:490)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:804)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:176)
    at com.demo.small.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:12)
Exception 2 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type InjectionPoint with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Dependent @Produces @ConfigProperty io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer.produceBooleanConfigProperty(InjectionPoint)
  at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer.produceBooleanConfigProperty(ConfigProducer.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Implicit Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Default],
  - Managed Bean [class io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigInjectionBean$InjectionPointMetadataInjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:386)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:526)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.CommonForkJoinPoolExecutorServices.lambda$wrap$0(CommonForkJoinPoolExecutorServices.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:391)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.quietlyJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:1079)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.invokeAll(ForkJoinPool.java:2725)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.AbstractExecutorServices.invokeAllAndCheckForExceptions(AbstractExecutorServices.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator.validateBeans(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:487)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:490)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:804)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:176)
    at com.demo.small.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:12)
```

Comment: What platform are you running on? Thorntail, WildFly? Or are you just trying to glue it together in pure SE?

Comment: @Siliarus Pure SE. code works fine in maven exec pluggin . But not working in executable jar